# Flex Navbar Loses Centering

Tags: css, flexbox, navbar, center

[Pen](https://codepen.io/tamjk/pen/MdBmNM) here.

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <div id="logo-div">
    MyLogo
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="item">LINK #1</li>
      <li class="item">LINK #2</li>
      <li class="item">LINK #3</li>
      <li class="item">LINK #4</li>
      <li class="item">LINK #5</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
}

#logo-div{
  margin-right: 50px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 60px;
}

nav{
  float: right;
}

.nav-list{
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  width: auto;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  width: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.item{
  background-color: #d6315d;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Typical website header with inline-block display, logo div on left and navbar on right.
I need to have flex-wrapping navbar to accommodate various device widths, at least until screen-width = 600px where it can be changed to a hamburger. So I make the nav-list height 3 times the height of the list item.
Problem is that if I float the nav block to the right within the header, the nav item-list will only wrap UNDER the logo-div, not beside it.
I can solve this by removing the float from the nav block altogether. But now the nav block drifts to the left on zoom, so the whole page looks off-center.

Anyone got any ideas ?

**EDIT**

[This CodePen](https://codepen.io/tamjk/pen/dybqKBN) achieves the desired effect of stacking nav items on rows within a navbar without the navbar spilling below the logo - at least till screen widths go below ~ 400px.

Comment: Wouldn't adding `  display: flex;` to the header solve it?

Comment: No, unfortunately. The nav item-list drifts to the left on zooming out.

Comment: https://codepen.io/tamjk/pen/dybqKBN   This solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are having an issue with the items not being aligned when the screen is smaller. The best way to do this is using `display: flex` to get alignment done easily. I have done a sample code and hope it helps your problem (`align-items-center` aligns all items including your logo to the center in the row when the screen size changes. If you don't need it you can remove it)

HTML

```
<header>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
    <div class="logo">
      MyLogo
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="item">LINK #1</li>
        <li class="item">LINK #2</li>
        <li class="item">LINK #3</li>
        <li class="item">LINK #4</li>
        <li class="item">LINK #5</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.item {
  background-color: #d6315d;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.align-items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

JS Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/7u36m194/

Comment: This is not the effect that I'm looking for. Doing this will not prevent the drift of the navbar to the left under zoom. It may also push the logo-div down.

Comment: Found a small improvement. Omit float altogether from <nav> and set the *justify-content* attribute of ul.nav-list to *space-evenly*. Probably better to use CSS grids in this situation.